# Simple formula for finding all rows that differ in exactly 1 digit

Tags: r

I have a matrix where each rows is a 10 digit string consisting of 0s and 1s.:

```
library(gtools)
a <- permutations(2, 10, v=c(0,1), repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

I would like to find for each row all other rows that differ in exactly 1 digit. All I need is a vector with the row ids of each string that differs in exactly 1 digit.

Is this possible to do somehow?

Comment: What do you mean *"each string"*? It's a matrix of 0s and 1s. Do you mean "each row that has at most one digit different than *this* row, repeated for each row"?

Comment: yes exactly thats what I mean

Comment: You should do: sum(xor(a[i,],a[j,]))==1 for all the combinations of i and j. If the result is TRUE the rows differ in just 1 position, or whatever condition you set. In general sum  xor will give you the number of differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are ordered as they are, you can interpret the "strings" as 0:1023 number sequence in base-2 numeral system. If we find the "numbers" which differ by 1 digit then their position is defined by number in decimal system.

```
b <- t(apply(a,1,function(x) {
  colSums(xor(diag(1, 10, 10)[,10:1], x) * (2^(9:0)) ) + 1
}))

# > head(b)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    2    3    5    9   17   33   65  129  257   513
# [2,]    1    4    6   10   18   34   66  130  258   514
# [3,]    4    1    7   11   19   35   67  131  259   515
# [4,]    3    2    8   12   20   36   68  132  260   516
# [5,]    6    7    1   13   21   37   69  133  261   517
# [6,]    5    8    2   14   22   38   70  134  262   518
```

You can check the above assumption by

```
strtoi(apply(a,1,paste, collapse = ""), base = 2)
```

#### Update

Frank (see comments) provided considerable faster and more nice-looking solution:

```
seq(2^10)-sweep(a-!a,2,as.integer(2^(9:0)),`*`)
```

Benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(times = 100,
  which = t(apply(a, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) which(colSums(x != t(a)) == 1))),
  symmetric = {
      aa    <- t(a)
      n <- nrow(a)
      neigh <- vector(n,mode="list")
      for (i in 1:(n-1)){
        rem        <- (i+1):n
        remmatch   <- rem[which(colSums(abs(aa[,rem,drop=FALSE]-aa[,i]))==1L)]
        neigh[[i]] <- c(neigh[[i]],remmatch)
        for (j in remmatch) neigh[[j]] <- c(neigh[[j]],i)
      }
  }, 
  numeral = t(apply(a,1,function(x) {
    colSums(xor(diag(1, 10, 10)[,10:1], x) * (2^(9:0)) ) + 1
  })),
  numeral_frank = seq(2^10)-sweep(a-!a,2,as.integer(2^(9:0)),`*`)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#          expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval  cld
#         which 163788.673 172454.3010 186222.9216 176371.6670 181390.4095 279304.441   100    d
#     symmetric  93525.411  96990.5505 104213.3545 100045.1590 101388.7930 193337.935   100   c 
#       numeral  26359.094  27974.7050  32738.9575  31785.5885  32383.6380 129262.575   100  b  
# numeral_frank    283.951    342.7515    506.8013    373.3275    420.5815   5199.634   100 a
```

Comment: I really like this idea. Here's a variant that is 5x as fast: `numeral2 = {aa <- matrix(as.logical(a),ncol=10); v <- as.integer(2^(9:0)); t(apply(aa,1,function(x)sum(v[x])+1L-(x-!x)*v))}` You can compare `sum(numeral2-numeral[,10:1]) # 0`

Comment: And even faster by another 14x is using entirely matrix operations: `numeral3 ={v <- as.integer(2^(9:0));ta <- t(a); va=v*ta;t(-va+v*(!ta))+colSums(va)+1L}`

Comment: And the last one: same speed, but more elegant... `numeral4 = {v <- as.integer(2^(9:0));seq(2^10)-sweep(a-!a,2,v,\`*\`)}`

Comment: @Frank impressive. I knew my solution is not tuned for performance (calculating constants and all inside a loop) but 14x is a surprise,,,

Comment: Oh, I meant "another 14x", so like 50x. Try `microbenchmark(
  numeral=t(apply(a,1,function(x) {
    colSums(xor(diag(1, 10, 10)[,10:1], x) * (2^(9:0)) ) + 1
  })),
  numeral3 ={v <- as.integer(2^(9:0));ta <- t(a); va=v*ta;t(-va+v*(!ta))+colSums(va)+1L},
  numeral4 = {v <- as.integer(2^(9:0));seq(2^10)-sweep(a-!a,2,v,\`*\`)}
  )`

Comment: @Frank Should expand `v` - but still very neat.

Comment: How can I modify the sweep solution to situations where the lenth of rows is not 10? what does the 9:0 stand for

Comment: To `seq(2^k)-sweep(a-!a,2,as.integer(2^((k-1):0)),`*`)`. But note that this answer has assumptions about `a` (all possible permutations and ordering).

Comment: @user1723765 use numeral3 version from the comments for different lengths of a

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```
b = t(apply(a, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) which(colSums(x != t(a)) == 1)))

    > head(b)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    3    5    9   17   33   65  129  257   513
[2,]    1    4    6   10   18   34   66  130  258   514
[3,]    1    4    7   11   19   35   67  131  259   515
[4,]    2    3    8   12   20   36   68  132  260   516
[5,]    1    6    7   13   21   37   69  133  261   517
[6,]    2    5    8   14   22   38   70  134  262   518
```

Comment: shouldn't each row have the same number of "neighbors"?

Comment: I agree with you, the number of neighbors should be the same since you have  calculated all the possible permutations. Each row will have 10 matching rows, 1 for each position.

Comment: Yup, got bit by the column-wise defaults. Replacing `rowSums` with `colSums` and adding a transpose fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

In the example given (of exhaustive enumeration of permutations), there are simpler answers, but here's how I would tackle the general case brought up in the question:

> I would like to find for each row all other rows that differ in exactly 1 digit.

Because the test for being a neighbor is symmetric, `function(x,y) sum(abs(x-y)) == 1`, we should only compare each pair of rows, `x` and `y`, at most once. We can do this in a loop, comparing row 1 against rows 2..n; then comparing 2 against 3..n; and so on:

```
n     <- nrow(a)
aa    <- t(a)

neigh <- vector(n,mode="list")
for (i in 1:(n-1)){

  # find matches
  rem        <- (i+1):n
  remmatch   <- rem[which(colSums(abs(aa[,rem,drop=FALSE]-aa[,i]))==1L)]

  # append matches
  neigh[[i]] <- c(neigh[[i]],remmatch)
  for (j in remmatch) neigh[[j]] <- c(neigh[[j]],i)
}
```

---

**Efficiency.** There are probably further improvements that could be made. For example, we know that our neighbors cannot be neighbors with each other and so needn't be compared. However, taking advantage of that would lead to a lot more code, I guess.